# Node.JS mongoose запрос с Q promise возвращает пустой {}

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

Использую mongoose и Q в качестве promises. Но результат - пустой {}

```
var Q = require("q");

var deferred = Q.defer();

User.find({}, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(next(err));
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(users);
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Такой же запрос с mongoose promise возвращает корректные данные, но в порядке простого calback:

```
console.log("Label 1");
console.log("Label 2 Users = " + getUsers());
console.log("Label 3");

...

getUsers = function(next) {
    User.find({}).exec().
        .then(function (err, users) {(
            if (users) {
                console.log("Label 4 Users = " + JSON.stringify(users));
                return user;
            }
        )}
        .catch(err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}
```

Результат:

Label 1 -> Label 2 -> Users = undefined -> Label 3 -> Label 4 Users = {...}

Node.Js v7.5; mongoose v4.8.3; q v1.4.1

Где ошибка? Как есть смысл использовать promise для вызова mongoose в функции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Ответ подсказали в английско ветке:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355139/node-js-mongoose-request-with-q-promise-return-empty